# Primitive to wrapper object conversion (behind the scenes)

Tags: javascript

Seems that if I wrap a string, boolean or number primitive value in `()` I get a String, Boolean, Number object which wraps the primitive value. Is this conclusion correct?

Also, it seems that the `()` are optional for strings and booleans but are required for numbers (to achieve the wrapping).

What is the general rule behind this behavior? What does wrapping in parentheses
actually do? And when is it mandatory to wrap and when is it optional to wrap in parentheses?

Example demonstrating this:

```
> "12345".concat("000")
'12345000'
> ("12345").concat("000")
'12345000'
> (true).valueOf()
true
> true.valueOf()
true
> (12345).toFixed()
'12345'
> 12345.toFixed()
Thrown:
12345.toFixed()
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

Comment: The issue with numeric constants is that the `.` is ambiguous: is it a decimal point (fraction separator) or is it the `.` to access a property? The parser assumes it's a fraction separator.

Comment: Thus `123.45.toString()` works fine

Comment: @Pointy Aaah, I see. That's why the `()` are required there. But is my conclusion correct - is there really a wrapping going on (from primitive value to wrapper object) in all these examples? I think there is.

Comment: `123.45.toFixed(1)` is maybe a better example, it also works fine. I get it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues here:

**Wrappers**

You get a wrapper object automatically created anytime you try to use a primitive as if it were an object (i.e. call a property or method). The system realizes that the primitive doesn't have any properties or methods, but knows that there is a corresponding Object type for the primitive, so it automatically wraps the primitive in an Object and carries out your property or method call.

**Parenthesis**

As noted in the comments, you need the parenthesis with numbers because the dot (.) could be a decimal point or an Object/property separator. The parenthesis clears up that ambiguity through syntax. ***The use of the parenthesis on  primitives does NOT cause the wrapper to be generated, it's the dot that does that.*** In those cases, the parenthesis is unneeded syntax that doesn't help or hurt.

```js
console.log((123.45).toFixed(1)); // Unambiguous. The parenthesis make it clear where the value ends

console.log(123.45.toFixed(1)); // Unambiguous. There can only be one decimal in a number.

//console.log(123.toFixed(1)); // Ambiguous. Is the dot a decimal or object/property separator
```

Comment: OK... got it. This answer sums it up really nicely. Thank you.

Comment: @peter.petrov Edited your edit to make it clear that **parenthesis do not ever cause wrappers to be created (even with numbers)**. It's always the `.` being used on a primitive that causes the wrapper object to be created. The parenthesis only clear up ambiguity about the purpose of the dot when it comes to numbers.

Comment: OK, thanks again. In fact it is not **always** the `.`, it can also be e.g. an indexer as in `"master"[1]`, this also causes wrapping of the primitive value `"master"` to a String object. I just realized that. Btw, shouldn't you say "parentheses" (plural) everywhere in your answer?